# Was Mjolnir also Hela's weapon?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

I watched *Thor: Ragnarok* yesterday and saw this scene where Hela, look above the ceiling and saw Thor, Loki, and Odin.

A picture of a "peaceful" Asgard. She then said the Odin is fond of "covering" up then proceeds to break the ceiling, revealing a picture of Odin and Hela. Then, I saw Hela, holding a hammer? is that Mjolnir? Was there any other reference in Marvel universe that Hela used Mjolnir? Or its just a depiction in the movie?

Comment: The reference in the answer is from Marvel Cinematic Universe only.

Comment: I found similar question in Sci-Fi SE. you can read it [**here**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174123/if-mjolnir-was-made-for-thor-why-is-hela-seen-using-it-in-thor-ragnarok-before)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It was Mjölnir wielded by Hela. This is only exclusive to Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Asgard forces headed by Hela conquered all the realms. But later when she became violent, Odin imprisoned her.

She says:

> We were unstoppable. 
>   I was his weapon in the conquest
>   that built Asgard's empire.
>   One by one, the realms became ours.
>   But then,
>   simply because my ambition outgrew his,
>   he banished me, caged me,
>   locked me away like an animal.

From [Springfield Springfield](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=thor-ragnarok).

If your next question is How could anyone else, that too evil one like Hela hold and break the hammer, Look for more details. [How can Hela hold or break Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81331/48608)

There were no enchantments on Mjolnir before Thor grew arrogant in *Thor*. So, Hela was able to use it without any problem.

Hela *does not* hold or break Mjolnir in the comics.

In the comics, she goes to an [alternate universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Marvel) to get Mjolnir and gift it to Thanos. But she fails to retrieve the hammer because she could not lift it. From [Hela (Earth-616)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hela_(Earth-616)),

> Disgraced, Hela allied herself with Thanos the Mad Titan to retake her kingdom, a favor he would do if she delivered a Mjolnir from a dead universe to him first. With Black Swan and Proxima Midnight by her side, Hela stole one of the Collector's retrieval shuttles to invade his great vessel, where the hammer was located. Hela ended up leading her allies into a brief fight against Beta Ray Bill and Odinson by mistakenly following the trail that led to Stormbreaker, Beta Ray Bill's hammer, **before taking them to the right hammer; only to discover it couldn't be lifted**. Hela and her companions of the Black Order were ultimately blasted into deep space by the Odinson when he reached the alternate Mjolnir and harnessed its power to defeat its would-be wielders.

The incident is from *Unworthy Thor 2-5*.

There are other instances hammer was destroyed and Thor found a replacement weapon.

Comment: So... Basically I would like to know if Mjolnir was Hela's weapon before Thor used the hammer. Because there was no other reference that Mjolnir was Hela's weapon, even in the scene where the Valkyrie attacks here, Hela uses her own blades, not the Mjolnir.

Comment: Yes. It is Hela's weapon before it came to Thor.

Comment: Turns out too that your linked post too has the answer to this question.